# Adding a single role to all server members

Tags: discord.py

So I am trying to make the bot give all the server members a single role. Code:

```
    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def test(self, ctx, role: discord.Role):
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
            await user.add_roles(role)
            print(f'{user.name}  {role.name}')
```

However, it only prints`Odysea(the name of my bot)  test role` And only gives the role to itself.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You need the members intent to do that. `intents = discord.Intents.default(); intents.members = True`

Comment: @EricJin do you mean in the commands.Bot()?

Comment: Yes, try instantiating with `Bot(prefix=whatever, ..., intents=intents)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comment section you can do like this.
`Ps. Im using client variable instead bot, that's up to you`

In `main` file

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=[your_prefix], intents=discord.Intents().all())
```

In `cogs`

```
@commands.command()
async def test(self, ctx, role:discord.Role):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.add_role(role)
        except:
            pass
        print(f"{member.name}, {role.name}")
```